# allow user access via ssh to /var/www/

Tags: permissions, files, git

Context: I am creating a gitolite3 hook for a specific repo, which contains some logic and css foo of my website.

so what essentailly happens is

Content under `/var/www/nginx/` looks like:

```
drwxrwxr-x. nginx   git   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 foo
```

`.git` is special:

```
drwxrwxr-x. git     git   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .git
```

To make sure all subdirs have the proper access rights I used:

```
chown nginx:git -Rf ./webfoo
chmod g+rw -Rf ./webfoo
chown git:git -Rf ./webfoo/.git
```

---

[This is just bonus, you can skip this.]

The gitolite3 hook

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/nginx/webfoo || exit
unset GIT_DIR
echo "where: $(pwd)"
git pull -f origin deploy-me-branch
```

---

```
remote: where: /var/www/nginx/webfoo
remote: From /home/gitolite/repositories/webfoo
remote:    c092ee2..07274a6  master     -> origin/master
remote: error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore' (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to unlink old 'templates/fancypost.html' (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to unlink old 'templates/layout.html' (Permission denied)
```

---

`/var/log/audit/audit.log` does not contain any access denies.

---

**Update:** Even loging in `git` locally does not work either. So this is probably **unrelated to SELinux/file security context**.

---

**Why does this fail to work as I'd expect?**

Comment: I suppose you've already done a `setenforce 0` to verify it actually is SELinux blocking the operation and not something else? Also where does that error output in the page (after your hook script) come from?

Comment: Just tried that to ensure, no change (as I expected, since `/var/log/audit/audit.log` contains nothing). So it is __not__ selinux related but I have no clue what it acutlly is...

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons why it did not work:

- **user** `git` should be member of **group** `git`
- do not pull/rebase as a different user, the `.git/*` might change ownership, this is especially when being logged in as `root`

---

A more elegant solution is to use `monit`, monitoring the repository under (as user `git`) `~/repositories` so I can also restart `nginx` and `uwsgi` if a executable webapp/file changed.